# Multiple template-dependent parameters

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, variadic-templates, c++-concepts

I'm not sure if the question name really reflects what I'm asking here, so please let me know if there are better titles.

I have a class that represents a value, which can be initialized either through a callable, or more cleanly through a reference to the variable.

```cpp
template <typename F> concept not_callable = !std::invocable<F>;

template <typename... Args>
struct Values{
  std::tuple<std::function<Args()>...> values;

  Values(std::invocable auto&&... func): values{std::make_tuple(std::function(func)...)} {}
  Values(not_callable auto&... args): values{std::make_tuple(std::function([&args](){return args;})...)} {}
};

Values(std::invocable auto&&... func) -> Values<std::remove_cvref_t<decltype(func())>...>;
Values(not_callable auto&... arg) -> Values<std::remove_cvref_t<decltype(arg)>...>;
```

This allows me to construct the function through either a series of functions, or references. However, I want to be able to initialize it with a mix of these.

```
int x;
char* y;
Values v1 (rand, clock);
Values v2 (x, y);
// Values v3 (x, rand); Doesn't work
```

Note that right now it fails because I have conflicting concepts for the constructors that won't allow both to be initialized together. However without the concepts, they don't compile at all. Is there a way to make this work?

An alternate solution is to have this class contain a tuple of another class, where that class is constructible from a single var or callable.

Unfortunately that would require syntax like the following with explicit casting for each parameter.

```
class singleV;
Value v4(singleV(x), singleV(rand));
```

Is there a way to be able to initialize it like `v3`?

Comment: "*either through a callable*" That's not what your code says. It says that it needs to be a nullary function that returns some type `T`. A mere "callable" won't do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a helper function to construct the corresponding `std::function` object according to the type of the argument

```
template <typename T> 
concept callable_or_variable = 
  std::invocable<T> || std::is_lvalue_reference_v<T>;

template <callable_or_variable T>
auto to_function(T&& t) {
  if constexpr (std::invocable<T>)
    return std::function<std::remove_cvref_t<std::invoke_result_t<T>>()>(t);
  else
    return std::function<std::remove_cvref_t<T>()>([&t] { return t; });
}
```

Then implement CTAD according to the return type of the `std::function` type returned by this helper function

```
template <typename... Args>
struct Values{
  std::tuple<std::function<Args()>...> values;

  Values(callable_or_variable auto&&... args): 
    values{to_function(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args))...} {}
};

template <callable_or_variable... Args>
Values(Args&&...) -> 
    Values<std::invoke_result_t<decltype(to_function(std::declval<Args>()))>...>;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/jzY4na4xa)

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you have two constructors, one constrained to accept only `std::invocable` parameters, and the other to accept only *non*-`std::invocable` lvalue reference parameters. First, we can write this out in non-terse syntax:

```
template<class... T>
requires (std::invocable<T> and...)
Values(T&&... func);

template<class... T>
requires ((not std::invocable<T> and std::is_lvalue_reference_v<T>) and...)
Values(T&&... args);
```

Then we can combine them into a single constructor:

```
template<class... T>
requires (std::invocable<T> and...) or ((not std::invocable<T> and std::is_lvalue_reference_v<T>) and...)
Values(T&&...);
```

Then, flip the logic so that instead of a disjunction of conjunctions we have a conjunction of disjunctions:

```
template<class... T>
requires ((std::invocable<T> or (not std::invocable<T> and std::is_lvalue_reference_v<T>)) and...)
Values(T&&...);
```

Simplifying:

```
template<class... T>
requires ((std::invocable<T> or std::is_lvalue_reference_v<T>) and...)
Values(T&&...);
```

This deals with the *declaration* of the constructor, it now remains to *define* it.

For the constructor initializer, you can use e.g. iifes:

```
template<class... T>
requires ((std::invocable<T> or std::is_lvalue_reference_v<T>) and...)
Values(T&&... args) : values{[&] {
    if constexpr (std::invocable<T>)
        return args;
    else
        return [&args] { return args; }
}()...} {}
```

And similarly for the ctad guides:

```
template<class... T>
requires ((std::invocable<T> or std::is_lvalue_reference_v<T>) and...)
Values(T&&... args) -> Values<std::remove_cvref_t<decltype([]{
    if constexpr (std::invocable<T>)
        return args();
    else
        return args;
}())>...>;
```

Comment: I haven't read your answer in detail, but it looks like the right solutions for me so far. But what's the purpose of "Flip the logic so that instead of a disjunction of conjunctions we have a conjunction of disjunctions." I will still do it because it looks a little cleaner, but is there a practical reason?

Comment: @Nathan29006781: "flip the logic"-> change the logic, it is not rewrite in another way.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, sorry I missed that

Comment: May as well also simplify the constraint: `requires ((std::invocable<T> or std::is_lvalue_reference_v<T>) and...)`.